# Adding rows to fit queries when there is data in rows below

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to insert a query into a spreadsheet that I has static cells.  I want to add query results from a range to a cell in the sheet, but there are static rows beneath it.  It would work okay if I were returning only a row or two, but there could be up to 60 rows from the query depending on the results.  I am trying to find a way to dynamically add a rows to fit the query when it exceeds the fixed rows in the sheet.

I tried looking into this, and I found this solution and the answer depicts the solution I want, but not the code?? Can someone please help me figure out how he did this? https://support.google.com/docs/thread/40944545?hl=en&msgid=40950847

Comment: `the answer depicts the solution I want, but not the code??` Have you read the answer and all the comments for that question and opened the OP's spreadsheets to see the answer by Ben Liebrand? He says `I entered the following formula into cell G1 [...] The Conditional formatting formula is the following Custome formula [...] Your formula is still in cell A2`. If you look in the OP's spreadsheet you'll see a sheet "Copy of Ben_Example_Sheet1" that contains his answer.